# Xamarin ListView: Expand Items

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to create a News page.

Right now I have an empty `ListView`. If I tap my `Button` a `ListView Item` is created.

On the next step I want to to be able to tap an `ListView Item`. When tapped I want a text to appear under the tapped Item.

Tap AddItem -> NewsArticle 1 is created -> Tap NewsArticle 1 -> NewsArticle 1 expands a text under it

Is something like this possible?

C#:

```
public partial class News : ContentPage
{

    ObservableCollection<NewsName> NewsItem = new ObservableCollection<NewsName>();
    int counter = 0;


    public News()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        NewsView.ItemsSource = NewsItem;
    }

     void AddArticle(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        counter++;
        NewsItem.Insert(0, new NewsName { NewsItem = "NewsArticle " + counter.ToString() });
    }

    public class NewsName
    {
        public string NewsItem { get; set; }
    }

}
```

XAML:

```
<StackLayout>
    <Label Text="Newss"></Label>
    <Button Clicked="AddArticle" Text="AddItem"></Button>
    <ListView x:Name="NewsView">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextCell Text="{Binding NewsItem}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView> 
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: In my experience, resizing the ViewCell leads to many rendering issues. I've handled this case using grouping. Move the ViewCell template to header template and show/hide the necessary things on its tap. May be this [ExpandableListView](https://umohammed.wordpress.com/2016/12/11/expandable-listview-in-xamarin-forms-using-grouping/) implementation can help

Answer (score 0):

In listview you have "Selected" property, it gives you the current selected item. You can add a gesture recognizer to each element - it will allow you to create an action when tapped.

Comment: Sorry but I am a bit lost. I added to new Items like this: "NewsItem.Add(new NewsName{NewsItem="Uno"}); 
But I couldnt figure out how to fire 2 different events on those Items. Like for example changing the "Newss" Label Text.

Answer (score 0):

You can custome **ListView.ItemTemplate** and use its **ItemSelected** can do that.

**XAML** like this:

```
  <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Monkeys}" 
              HasUnevenRows="true" 
              ItemTapped="OnListViewItemTapped"
              ItemSelected="OnListViewItemSelected">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Margin="10"  VerticalOptions="Center">
                            <Label  x:Name="label"
                               Text="{Binding Location}"
                               VerticalOptions=" />
                            <Button Grid.RowSpan="2"
                                    Grid.Column="2"
                                    Text="Click"
                                    HorizontalOptions="End"
                                    Clicked="OnClicked"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

And you need create a ViewModel to be binded to xaml.

**ViewModel** like this:

```
class MonkeysViewModel
{
    public IList<Monkey> Monkeys { get; private set; }
    public MonkeysViewModel()
    {
        Monkeys = new List<Monkey>();
        //f = new F[5];
        Monkeys.Add(new Monkey
        {
            Name = "Baboon",
            Location = "Africa & Asia"
        });
    }
 }

  class Monkey : INotifyPropertyChanged
 {
   private string name = "520";
   public string Name
    {
        set
        {
            if (name != value)
            {
                name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }
        get
        {
            return name;
        }
    }

   public string Location { get; set; }

   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;


    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
 }
```

Last in ContentPage you should bind the modle and add EventHandle

**ContentPage** like this:

```
  BindingContext = new MonkeysViewModel();

  async void OnListViewItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
       //do your listView selected method
    }
   void OnClicked(Object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
       //do your each list's button clicked method
    }
```

Notice : If you want value of modle be dynamic , need use **INotifyPropertyChanged**